# Markdown Nested List tabs are off

Tags: list, nested, markdown, readme.io

I have a nested list in Markdown (on readme.io) that is coded as such:

```
 1. Select **New Email** from the top right of the **Suggested Post** window.  
 - **Add A Photo**
 - **Insert Showcase Link**: Adds a link as a central focus of the email by including an image, header, brief description and URL of the link.

  *If the recipient clicks the showcase link **or any link** within the email, the action will be tracked and analytic data collected. This information can be viewed within the **Performance** section.*

  -  **Insert Variable**:  Include a variable within the body or subject of your message. Click within the body or subject line areas then select **Insert Variable** where the variable should appear in the message. Variable information can be either **Contact** or **Agent** information. Users can select from **First Name**, **Last Name**, and **Email**.  
  - **Modification Rule**: A rule specifying how a post can be modified can be selected by choosing optional, prohibited or required.  
    * **Optional**: The text can be modified.  
    * **Prohibited**: The text cannot be modified. **Note**: Only email content set to **Prohibited** will appear in the Hearsay Mobile Application within the **Outreach** tab under **Email Templates**.  
    * **Required**: The post will have sections enclosed in brackets that require the user to edit prior to being published.
```

And renders fine:

1. Select **New Email** from the top right of the **Suggested Post** window.

   - **Add A Photo**
   - **Insert Showcase Link**: Adds a link as a central focus of the email by including an image, header, brief description and URL of the link.

   *If the recipient clicks the showcase link **or any link** within the email, the action will be tracked and analytic data collected. This information can be viewed within the **Performance** section.*

   - **Insert Variable**:  Include a variable within the body or subject of your message. Click within the body or subject line areas then select **Insert Variable** where the variable should appear in the message. Variable information can be either **Contact** or **Agent** information. Users can select from **First Name**, **Last Name**, and **Email**.
   - **Modification Rule**: A rule specifying how a post can be modified can be selected by choosing optional, prohibited or required.
   - **Optional**: The text can be modified.
   - **Prohibited**: The text cannot be modified. **Note**: Only email content set to **Prohibited** will appear in the Hearsay Mobile Application within the **Outreach** tab under **Email Templates**.
   - **Required**: The post will have sections enclosed in brackets that require the user to edit prior to being published.

However, if I add another top level bullet, the Modification Rule bullets tabs its content to be even with its sublist.

[image]

How can I correct this?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. What browser do you use?

Comment: I am using Chrome.

Comment: I tried recreating this in several different browsers on different operating systems, without avail.